# Third-party js lib not being displayed in canvas LWC (Fabric.js lib)

Tags: lightning-web-components, js, libraries, third-party, html2canvas

I'm trying to display some shapes using the [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) library.
From the console, seems like the fabric.canvas is built correctly, but nothing is being rendered.
My code:

**HTML**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="testFabric" icon-name="custom:custom19">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
            <canvas
                    width="500"
                    height="500"
                    id="c"
                    class="c"
                    lwc:dom="manual"
            ></canvas>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import fabricLib from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fabric';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
       
export default class ShowShapes extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    //retrieve canvase and context
    renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, fabricLib + '/fabric.min.js')
        ])
            .then(() => {
                console.log(fabric?.Canvas, 'canvas');

                let canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

                console.log(canvas, 'created canvas');

                var rect = new fabric.Rect({left: 100,top: 50,fill: '#D81B60',width: 50,height: 50,strokeWidth: 2,stroke: "#880E4F",rx: 10,ry: 10,angle: 45,scaleX: 3,scaleY: 3,hasControls: true});

                canvas.add(rect);
                console.log(canvas);
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
                canvas.renderAll();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error loading Fabric',
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }
}
```

Console logs:
[image]

LWC canvas:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm afraid that [Lightning Locker](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_locker_service) won't allow you to use that js lib, for the several reasons:

1. `new fabric.Canvas()` constructor can take either `<canvas>` element or its `id` to initialize an instance on. Passing the `id` invokes `document.getElementById(id)` method under the hood but Locker will return null. It is possible to pass the  element into the `fabric.Canvas` constructor directly adding the `data-id` attribute to the `canvas`:

**HTML**

```html
<canvas
    width="500"
    height="500"
    class="c"
    data-id="c"
    lwc:dom="manual"
></canvas>
```

**JS**

```js
const canvasEl = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="c"]');
let canvas = = new fabric.Canvas(canvasEl);
```

2. But then you face another problem is that the `lwc:dom="manual"` directive makes it possible to call the `appendChild()` method on the HTMLElement to manually insert the DOM. This does not mean it is allowed to perform `element.parentNode.replaceChild(e, t)` not to mention the manipulation of global objects such as `window`, `document`, etc.

Unfortunately, `Fabric.js` library tries to create a parent wrapper element (`<div class='canvas-container'/>`) during the initialization phase and, for obvious reasons (lwc:dom="manual" element must be empty), Locker throws an error:

> Error: Access denied: {"from":{"namespace":"c"}}

That is, in order for this library to be compatible with Locker, it must be rewritten taking into account at least the above restrictions.

But there is also **good** news.

Recently there was introduced [Lightning Web Security (LWS)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_intro) a new client-side security architecture for Lightning Web Components.

> Lightning Web Security is designed to make it easier for your components to use secure coding practices and aims to replace Lightning Locker for Lightning web components (LWC). It works along with Lightning Locker, which is still used for Aura components.

> Lightning Web Security (LWS) is modeled after the latest TC39 standards to provide innovative usable security for any UI component. This approach enables teams to safely use code from third parties without fear of threats such as cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. The result is a more secure way to control the execution of code within the UI layer without forcing developers to jump through hoops or abandon desired functionality.

Before enabling LWS you should consider the next things:

1. If you want to do it in your scratch org/sandbox it is OK.
2. If you want to enable LWS in your production org please read [When to Enable Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_when).

If all requirements are taken into account and met, in order to enable LWS in your org go to

```
Setup -> Home -> Security -> Session Settings
```

On the `Session Settings` page, select `Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components` and save.

Clear your browser cache after enabling or disabling Lightning Web Security to ensure the correct files are loaded in the browser.

Having that done, just look at this beauty:

[image]

It is even draggable, resizable, and rotatable:

[image]

It's safe to say that LWS is a revolution in Salesforce front-end development. **Thanks to all those who participated in its development**.

Comment: Hi Oleh, I was afraid that it's being caused by the Locker Service.
Thanks a lot for suggesting switching to the LWS, totally didn't think about that.
Seems like it's working now!